# Combine RedirectMatch and ProxyPass in Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have enabled HTTPS for a site and all requests to HTTP should be redirected to HTTPS now, **except** for the content of one directory, e.g. `/downloads`.

I changed my VirtualHost configuration for HTTP as follows and added the `RedirectMatch` setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName              example.com
        RedirectMatch           302 ^/(?!download/).*$ https://example.com$1
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPass               /       http://10.0.0.11:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse        /       http://10.0.0.11:3000/
</VirtualHost>

# configuration for HTTPS down here, working fine
```

My expectation: Requests such as `http://example.com/faq` would be redirected to the HTTPS version, and all requests such as `http://example.com/download/file.zip` would still be HTTP.

But obviously, the `Proxy*` instructions take higher precedence and no redirect at all takes place.

How would I have to structure my configuration correctly, so that I can use the `RedirectMatch`, and in case it does not match uses the `Proxy*` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, didn't see the forest for the trees. Solution was as easy as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName              example.com
        RedirectMatch           302 ^/(?!download/).*$ https://example.com$1
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPass               /download/       http://10.0.0.11:3000/download/
        ProxyPassReverse        /download/       http://10.0.0.11:3000/download/
</VirtualHost>
```

So, the Proxy directives only kick in for the routes which are excluded by `RedirectMatch`.